# Cloning the content and styling of one sheet to another - PHP Excel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I need to copy the content of one sheet in an Excel Workbook to a sheet in a new excel workbook. The issue is, I have no idea what the sheets contain or their formatting. However, it will only be the first sheet every time.

I've tried an approach but I run out of memory every time. So I thought I'd do it row by row for 100 000 rows. Anyway, I started with a row, and it gets the data, but no luck in writing it to a new sheet. How would I do that?

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Open the current worksheet
App::import('Vendor', 'PHPExcel');
if (!class_exists('PHPExcel')) {
    throw new CakeException('Vendor class PHPExcel not found!');
$this->xls = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);

// Read all content
$this->xls->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:ZZZZ1');

// Close current worksheet
$this->xls->disconnectWorksheets();

// Delete worksheet
unlink($destination);

// Open new worksheet
$this->xls = new PHPExcel();
$newWorksheet = new PHPExcel_Worksheet($this->xls, 'Sheet 1');
$this->xls->addSheet($newWorksheet);
$this->xls->setActiveSheetIndexByName('Sheet 1');

// Write all the content
$this->xls->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($array,null,'A1');

// Save current worksheet
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->xls, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save($destination);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Then also, is there an easier way to do this? I don't want to write all this code and in the end it's all reinventing the wheel?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a built-in method that's specifically written to do this for you:

```
$objPHPExcel1 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
$objPHPExcel2 = new PHPExcel();

// Copy active worksheet from $objPHPExcel1 to $objPHPExcel2
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel1->getActiveSheet();
$objPHPExcel2->addExternalSheet($worksheet)
```

and if you're running out of memory, building large arrays in memory to try and copy manually isn't going to help.

There are approaches designed to reduce memory such as cell caching, look to use those to reduce memory usage

Comment: Is there a way that I can force it to read only values and styling, and not formulas?

Comment: Uh, no... what's your problem with formulas? They're the content of a cell/cells. And why don't you want them?

Comment: No real problem. Just don't see the point of them if they aren't going to be used in the resulting sheets. I suppose there's no real harm in keeping them... Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @Albert I know this is old, but you can manually iterate through all the cells and check for values starting with "=" and use getCalculatedValue() to convert them all

Comment: @MarkBaker how can we do the same for copying the content from different files.