# Clone Google Workbook and embed to HTML

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a fairly complex Excel file (no macros) which has thousands of functions and about 10 - 15 sheets.
The first sheet has some cells as input which  of what creates the rest of the sheets' cell values.
I managed to successfully import this to Google Sheets.

1. Is it possible to load (clone) an entrire workbook in PHP ? (Make a Copy in File menu)
   The examples I've seen on stackoverflow etc are cloning / copying a worksheet to a new sheet. I want to copy an existing workbook.
2. How do I embed the newly cloned workbook to an HTML page ? I won't be able to know the embed code before hand since Im clonig it via PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the sample code in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774486/cloning-the-content-and-styling-of-one-sheet-to-another-php-excel).

> There's a built-in method that's specifically written to do this for you:
>
> ```
> $objPHPExcel1 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
> $objPHPExcel2 = new PHPExcel();
>
> // Copy active worksheet from $objPHPExcel1 to $objPHPExcel2
> $worksheet = $objPHPExcel1->getActiveSheet();
> $objPHPExcel2->addExternalSheet($worksheet)
> ```
>
> and if you're running out of memory, building large arrays in memory
>   to try and copy manually isn't going to help.
>
> There are approaches designed to reduce memory such as cell caching,
>   look to use those to reduce memory usage

Here's a sample [script](https://github.com/Pco-A2IT/IHM-Final/blob/a4c425af61c254a0dc0dbdc55c62400e91fe9e0b/PHPExcel-1.8/Examples/43mergeWorkbooks.php) which demonstrates how `addExternalSheet()` copies the styling as well as the content from one workbook to another.